# Postgresql refusing TCP/IP connection after ubuntu restart

Tags: postgresql, tcp-ip

This one has me baffled.

I rebooted my ubuntu server and now I try to connect with pgadmin and I get the following:

```
could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "<ip.address>" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In my postgresql.conf file

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

In my pg_hba.conf

```
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5



host    all     all     129.125.179.201/32      trust
host    all     all     86.81.139.21/24         trust
```

I added the following line to the end

```
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       md5
```

Still can't connect

I've restarted postgresql after every change.

I can log in to postgresql via the command line via shh.

I'm out of ideas!

#### Edit

iptables

```
sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
```

Netstat results

```
netstat -lt4
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:8787                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:postgresql            *:*                     LISTEN
```

iptables-save

```
sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Sep 23 18:23:36 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [48958:12725477]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2847:159736]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [70:6309]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [70:6309]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 23 18:23:36 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Sep 23 18:23:36 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 23 18:23:36 2017
```

Comment: You don't have a firewall running by any chance, do you?

Comment: not one I set up, but how do you check? As I said it was running normally before the reboot. Although I did do a apt-get install postgis* to install scripts as I was trying to get pg_pointclouds setup.

Comment: `sudo iptables -S`. If you're connecting from the same machine, you might also want to try `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5`.

Comment: I've added the out put of the iptables, the machine is at work, i'm using putty ssh to connect. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5 is already set under the local connections.

Comment: Do you see the PostgreSQL port listening when running `netstat -lt4`? Post results

Comment: it's listed, results appended to the post above.

Comment: You don't mention through what interface the connection is attempted. Based on the error message, I'm  guessing it's from another machine, so not through the `lo` interface and then that rule: `-A INPUT -j DROP` applies and rightfully blocks the connection. Suggestion: add a rule above for port 5432, same sort of what is already there for 80 and 443.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not related with authorization (eg. pg_hba.conf) as your error suggest unreachable port. Try to point as much connection parameters as you can. Also try to connect using some simple tool like psql (with all connection parameters given, eg. -h localhost -U user -W -p 5432, etc.) This should give you some hint about what is going on and where to look futher.

Especially give him -h localhost, as it will otherwise use local unix socket insteed of TCP

EDIT: Are you sure, that this is good iptable rule:
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
I am no expert here, but try to temporary remove this entry and connect again. Same concern about: -A INPUT -j DROP

EDIT2: If nothing works, please dump all iptables by "iptables-save" insteed of "iptables -S". "iptables-save" dump all available tables (eg. filter, nat, etc.). More info in manual

Comment: psql -U <username> -h <ip.address> -W -p 5432 works fine from the shell, it says: psql (9.5.8)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)

Comment: as for iptables, last time I tried to alter them I ended up doing a fresh install

Comment: how should I remove them using the commandline - and more importantly, how should I put them back? Sorry, I'm still learning the complexities of linux.

Comment: Carefully read iptable manual, there is everything you need to know. BUT if you are able to connect with psql, the same connect parameters should works with pgadmin3. Check for any connection parameters diffrents

Comment: Hey, you posted, that you were able to successfully connect though psql - did you first connect to server using ssh? If true, DO NOT! Run psql on the very same system as you trying to run pgadmin3

Comment: pgadmin was connecting fine yesterday, no reason why it shouldn't connect today, I've reinstalled pgadmin, setup a new server group etc, still the same issue. Yet I can connect via commandline.

Comment: yes,I connected via ssh on this laptop, I'll see what happens via my desktop...

Comment: same issue on my desktop, so a server side issue

Comment: not exactly.  Localhost is working on server, so the problem is visibility of that port from nat. Post all iptables entries (iptables-save) along with server interfaces (you can "mask" IPs for security reason if you need, but do it carefully as this could obviously distort data and prohibit you from reaching solution here ;) )

Comment: I've been googling ip tables, so you want sudo iptables and what flags?

Comment: simply: sudo iptables-save

Comment: added to the above

Comment: I can connect to pgadmin on the localhost (putty + x11) so the issue must be related to the iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you possibly remove it from /etc/services

You should have a line that looks like this

```
    postgresql      5432/tcp        postgres        # PostgreSQL Database
```